# Related Object Query Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing a blog site for practice. My problem is I can't call data from one object to another related object.

Here are my model associations:

```
1 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
2   belongs_to :user
3 end

1 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
2   has_many :posts
3 end
```

In the console:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.posts // Everything works! It shows me a list of posts related to the user.
user.post(1) //This doesn't work! Is it wrong?
```

I've been looking over active record query interface guide at rubyonrails.org and still can't find anything in reference to this. Maybe I missed something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
user.posts[0]  #=> returns the user's first post
```

Comment: user.posts.first is also an alternative way to joel's answer.

Comment: Hey! This works! If I wanted to do user.create_posts, would that work as well? Where could I look to get more info?

Comment: Also, is there a method like 'user.find_posts(x)' that I could use instead of users.posts[x]?